# Why FormulaR1C1 does occure Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that use two formulas. But when i try to run it I've got Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Here's my code:

```
Private Function PutFormulaIn(ColumnChar As String, MinRangeNum As Integer, MaxRangeNum As Integer, NewFormulaR1C1 As String)  
        
        Range(ColumnChar & MinRangeNum).FormulaR1C1 = NewFormulaR1C1
        
        Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnChar & MinRangeNum)
        Set fillRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnChar & MinRangeNum & ":" & ColumnChar & MaxRangeNum)
        SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
        
    End Function

    
Sub CreateCustumSheet()
   Dim months
   months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May")
   Dim formulaRow as String
   Dim formulaVLook as String
   formulaRow = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC2);"""";ROW(RC1))"
   formulaVLook = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC7);"""";(VLOOKUP(RC7;Dict!R2C4:R48C5;2;0))"

   For i = LBound(months) To UBound(months)
      If ActiveSheet.Name = months(i) Then
         Call PutFormulaIn ("A",2,1000,formulaRow)
         Call PutFomulaIn ("I",2,1000,formulaVLook)
         Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = months(i+1)
      Else
         Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = months(i)
         Call PutFormulaIn ("A",2,1000,formulaRow)
         Call PutFomulaIn ("I",2,1000,formulaVLook)
      End If
   Next i
```

I know that the problem is with this line:

```
Range(ColumnChar & MinRangeNum).FormulaR1C1 = NewFormulaR1C1
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Use commas, not semicolons, in your formula strings. That property expects US regional settings,

Comment: @Rory Unfortunately, there is still the same problem

Comment: Please update the question with the current code you are using, and confirm which line is in error.

Comment: Check parenthesis, I think you added more than needed. The parenhtesis before `VLOOKUP`, why? And Also, as @Rory suggested, use commas, not semicolons. IT should be `"=IF(ISBLANK(RC7),"""",VLOOKUP(RC7,Dict!R2C4:R48C5,2,0))"`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yup, there was a mistake. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check parenthesis, I think you added more than needed. The parenthesis before `VLOOKUP`, why? And Also, as @Rory suggested, use commas, not semicolons. It should be

```
"=IF(ISBLANK(RC7),"""",VLOOKUP(RC7,Dict!R2C4:R48C5,2,0))"
```